# MySQL exchange rate with date query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with exchange rates by date and a second table with customers sales.

```
TableA:
    date of excahnge_rate
    from_currency
    to_currency

TableB:
    customerid
    total_bought
    user_currency
    date_bought
```

I need to get a table with the `total_bought` transformed into the same currency, so I need to check the `exchange_rate` on each `date_bought` and apply the rate on that date.

I would get the same TableB but with the `total_bought` in the same currency for all the records.

I'm an unexperienced user of SQL and I'm having troubles with this.

Comment: can you show us what you tried so far? Also some example data and the desired output of the query (based on the example data) would make the question a _lot_ easier to understand - remember we are not familiar with your schema, data model or business logic.

Comment: It'd be good if you provide a sample data from the two table you have specified